# Why will a non-black body of a temperature the same as that of the internal walls of a cavity be in thermal equilibrium, if brought into the cavity?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, equilibrium

The book of Zemansky and Dittman claims that:

> [image: one]
>   [image: two]

I am confused with the first line of the second picture.

What is written, actually means that if the temperature of the body is the same as that of the walls, it will be equilibrium.

Why is that?

In other words, one could say **What does equilibrium in a cavity for a body inside mean?**

Comment: If it has the same temperature - it is in equilibrium; its temperature won't change.

Comment: @RobJeffries Why? It is not an assumption. There must be a reasoning.

Comment: Zeroth law of thermodynamics.

Comment: @RobJeffries How? It's not obvious for me. Can you explain in more details?

Comment: see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78783/definitions-in-thermodynamics-temperature-thermal-equilibrium-heat?rq=1

Comment: @RobJeffries Heat exchange does not necessarily mean temperature change.