# Thermal equilibrium, heat and temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, definition, equilibrium

I am just studying thermodynamics for the first time and confused between these three terms
**Temperature** is defined in terms of thermal equilibrium (from zeroth law of thermodynamics) and **thermal equilibrium** is defined in terms of heat(no net heat flow) and we defined **heat** in terms of temperature (heat is energy transfer due to temperature difference).Isn't this a circular definition.
Can you please give authentic definitions of these three terms  THERMAL EQUILIBRIUM ,TEMPERATURE and HEAT that is independent of each other and please mention the source for further reading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Definitions in thermodynamics: temperature, thermal equilibrium, heat](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78783/)